# Can't increment variable in bash shorthand if else condition

Tags: bash

In this example "normal" if else is working as expected incrementing counter:

```
fail_count=0
for i in {1..1000}; do
    curl --fail -sL "$URL/$i"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ((fail_count++)); else fail_count=0; fi
    echo $fail_count
    [[ $fail_count -eq 10 ]] && exit 0
done
```

and here `fail_count` value is always 0:

```
fail_count=0
for i in {1..1000}; do
    curl --fail -sL "$URL/$i"
    [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && ((fail_count++)) || fail_count=0
    echo $fail_count
    [[ $fail_count -eq 10 ]] && exit 0
done
```

Incrementing works when counter variable is not set in `|| fail_count=0` part.

So what is the difference?

Comment: see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3

Comment: If `fail_count` gets to the threshold, it seems you really ought to `exit 1`

Comment: That's the problem with `short-circuits`, you get electrocuted :-)

Comment: Look mah, no `[ $? -ne 0 ]` test  `if curl.... ; then ((fail_count++)); else fail_count=0; fi`

Comment: In original script I'm taking the output to var=$(curl.... )

Comment: The assignment has a useful exit status as well, so it should work without the test for the `[ $? -ne 0 ]`, now if only `$(( $? > 0 ?  ((fail_count++)) : fail_count=0  ))`  If this will work, that would be nice otherwise I'm just dreaming :-)

Comment: It's working with small change `(( $? > 0 ? ((fail_count++)) : ((fail_count=0)) ))`

Comment: @Catnip The nested parens aren't necessary FWIW.

Comment: I can get it to work like this `(( $? > 0 ? fail_count++ : (fail_count=0) ))` but without parens around assignment I get `attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=0 ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [textbook example](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) of why `a && b || c` is a bad idea. The problem is that if `b` fails then it will also execute `c`. You can have both `b` and `c` run, a problem if-then-else doesn't have.

Does that apply here? It sure does. See, the return value of `fail_count++` is the value of `fail_count` prior to incrementing -- `0`. And `((0))` is considered a failure and causes it to return with a non-zero exit code. Which triggers `fail_count=0`, resetting it back to zero every iteration.

**Lesson:** Avoid `a && b || c`. It's short. And dangerous.