# bash chains doesn't execute the second command but does for the third

Tags: bash, shell, testing

I am trying to replace all the if statements in my bash scripts with test and &&/|| because it's way easier to read for me, but I have trouble with this script, it's testing if $1 is a file and if it's not it exits

```
test -f "$1" || echo "$1 is not a file" && exit 1
```

When $1 is a file the echo command isn't executed but exit is, why ?
For information I am using bash 5.1.8

Comment: Your code is no replacement for `if ... then ...; else ...; fi`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against trying to use `&&`/`||` in place of `if` statements. They may be easier to read, but they're much harder to understand. Their semantics can easily lead to unexpected interactions between the various commands involved; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217624/cant-increment-variable-in-bash-shorthand-if-else-condition) and [this BashPitfalls entry](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).

Comment: @SirCipherz : When $1 is a plain file, `test -f ...` sets exit code 0, which means that the command after `||` is not performed. This is by design of the `||` statement separator. Why did you expect something different?

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what `&&/||` means - it's not a ternary expression.

- `&&` means "if the last command you executed succeeded" while
- `||` means "if the last command you executed failed"

That "last command executed" part is important. It doesn't say "the command before the first `||` or `&&` on the line", as would be the case in a similar ternary expression structured as `test ? exit : echo`, it says **the last command executed** so in your code:

```
test -f "$1" || echo "$1 is not a file" && exit 1
```

it reads as pseudo-code:

```
IF test fails (i.e. $1 is not a file) THEN
    IF echo ... succeeds THEN
        exit 1
    ENDIF
ELSE (i.e. test succeeded and $1 is a file)
    exit 1
ENDIF
```

I think what you probably meant to write is:

```
test -f "$1" || { ret="$?"; echo "$1 is not a file" >&2; exit "$ret"; }
```

which means:

```
IF test fails (i.e. $1 is not a file) THEN
    save it's exit status in ret
    echo ...
    exit with the failure exit status from test
ENDIF
```