# Run commands on same line as [[ ]] operator

Tags: bash, shell

I am attempting to use the [[ ]] operator in Bash and failing badly.
My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Test driver for the ProtectDatae script 
set -o xtrace
# [[ -z "$1" ]] || source="$1" && source=""
if [[ -z "%1" ]]
then
  source=""
else
  source=$1
fi
[[ -z "$2" ]] || target="$2" && target="" # This does not work
[[ -z "$3" ]] || sourceBackup="$3" && sourceBackup="/tmp/sourcebackup" # This does not work
source cmd.sh  # Get a function to run a Linux command
if [[ -e "$sourceBackup" && "$sourceBackup" -ne "" ]]
then
  # If a source backup directory is specified then get rid of any old directory and make a new backup
  # and verify it. If OK, make the source directory be the source backup directory
  # otherwise work directly in the source directory
  if [[ -e "$sourceBackup" ]]
  then
    cmd "sudo rm -R $sourceBackup" "empty backup directory $sourceBackup failed"
    cmd "cp -apu $source $sourceBackup" "backup home directory"
    cmd "diff -aprN ~/$source/* $sourceBackup" "bad backup in $sourceBackup"
    source="$sourceBackup"
 fi
fi

exit 0
```

My command invocation is `./TestProtectData.sh "~" /tmp/jfghome /tmp/jfgbackup`

The result of xtrace is:

```
+ source='~'
+ [[ -z /tmp/jfghome ]]
+ target=/tmp/jfghome
+ target=""
+ [[ -z /tmp/jfgbackup ]]
+ sourceBackup=/tmp/jfgbackup
+ sourceBackup=/tmp/sourcebackup
+ source cmd.sh
+ [[ -e /tmp/sourcebackup ]]
+ exit 0
```

What happens with the following line is the error. Both alternatives appear to be executed and the variable winds up being set incorrectly:

```
[[ -z "$2" ]] || target="$2" && target=""
```

I have tried both orders for && and || and they both give the same result with the variable `target` set to blank. On the next line, a similar thing happens with the variable `sourceBackup` set to the second alternative, and both alternatives appear to be executed. If I use the `if then` construct it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `%1` a typo?

Comment: I suggest to use `if ...; then ...; else ...; fi`

Comment: I am aware that construct works. I am trying to learn how to use [[ ]] which is more compact.

Comment: @Jonathan The basic problem here is that you're trying to use `&&` and `||` instead of `if ... then ... else ... fi`, and they're not equivalent. They can be close, but there are weird potential problems (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217624/cant-increment-variable-in-bash-shorthand-if-else-condition)), and constructs with weird potential problems are things you should avoid. Also, in the case of default parameter values, there's a much better method: `sourceBackup="${3:-/tmp/sourcebackup}"` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332802#9333006)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your intended logic doesn't match the bash constructs you're using.  This line:

> ```
> [[ -z "$2" ]] || target="$2" && target="" # This does not work
> ```

Breaks down to mean `if 2 is not empty set target to $2.  If that command succeeds, set target to ""`. The command to the left of `&&` will always succeed - either the `-z` test succeeds or the `target="$2"` succeeds.  Thus `target=""` always runs at the end.

You can use `if ... ; then ...; else ...; fi` or you can [look at these ways to effect a ternary operator in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash), including:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
[[ -z "$3" ]] && sourceBackup="/tmp/sourcebackup" || sourceBackup="$3"
echo $sourceBackup
```

```
% ./t.sh 1 2 3                                                                                                                                                            
3
```

Here, if `-z` test succeeds we set `sourceBackup` to the default.  If the test fails, `$3` is not null and we set `sourceBackup` to `$3`.

To reiterate, this is *not* exactly the same as a tertiary operator.  But if you get the order correct, it will work.

Comment: erik258, Your example```[[ -z "$3" ]] && sourceBackup="/tmp/sourcebackup" || sourceBackup="$3"``` does not seem to work. It gives the second alternative when $3 is not empty.

Comment: Is that not what you want?  You'll notice the first alternative is setting to the default if $3 *is* empty.

Comment: erik258, thanks. I mixed things up when trying it.

Answer (score 1):

A plain assignement (`foo=bar`) always sets the status code to 0, so after `target` has been set to `$2`, it is immediately after set to empty. I would start by turning the logic inside out:

```
target= # Set to empty string
[[ -z $2 ]] && target=$2
```

However, this is redundant. You could easier simply just write

```
target=$2
```

without doing any `[[...]]`-test. If the second parameter is empty, `target` will be empty as well. If it is not empty, `target` will get that value.

There is one point to consider: In case you decide to turn on `set -u`, to catch uninitialized variables, a `target=$2` would abort the script if there is no second parameter. Therefore, you could also write

```
target=${2:-}
```

which tells bash that a missing parameter is OK and should be treated as a null string.

Even though it is redundant, if you do **not** turn on `-u`, using `${2:-}` shows your intent explicitly, and makes your program more maintainable.