# One liner if-else not working as intended

Tags: bash, if-statement, one-liner

I made a simple script on WSL for windows 11 to mount my pen drive. The default option is to mount it from D:, and I can specify as an argument if the pen drive is in another place.

The script is like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

[[ $# -eq 0 ]] && sudo mount -t drvfs D: /pen || sudo mount -t drvfs ${1}: /pen

[[ $? == 0 ]] && echo "Good" || echo "Bad"
```

It works when the pen drive is connected on port D:, but when there is no pen drive connected, the first command executes both sides of the OR.

I am expecting it to execute on the same basis of al if-else statement.
If the condition is true, it executes the left side, and if it is false, it executes the right side.

Comment: The precedence of && and || are equal in bash, they are interpreted left-to-right.

Comment: In your command `A && B || C`, the `C` will execute if `B` fails. You may want to add parenthesis like `(A && B) || C`?

Comment: The `&& ... ||` trick is *not* equivalent to an `if ... then ... else ... fi`. Don't use it, it just doesn't work. See [BashPitfalls #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) and  ["Can't increment variable in bash shorthand if else condition"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217624/cant-increment-variable-in-bash-shorthand-if-else-condition).

Comment: I would just use `if...else` at this point, but if you insist on keeping this form, you can do: `A && { B; true; } || C`

Comment: Actually, in this case you could skip the conditional entirely, and use an [alternate value substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332802/how-to-write-a-bash-script-that-takes-optional-input-arguments/9333006#9333006) to make "D" the default parameter: `sudo mount -t drvfs "${1:-D}:" /pen`

Comment: The command does not make sense to me. You try to mount the pen drive on D:, and if this fails you try to mount it again for drive $1. However, since you have established that $# is zero, you don't have a parameter $1.

Comment: @GordonDavisson okay, I thought it was the same. I'm using a normal "if-else" from now on. Thank you.

Comment: @user1934428 I thought that this form is the same as an "if-else" clause. What I was trying to do is to mount it differently depending on if the arguments exists or does not.

Comment: @Pau: Of course you can always write a normal `if`....`fi` into a single line, if you want. Statements are separated by **either** newlines **or** semicolons.

Comment: Just remember that `A && B || C` does not equal `if A then B else C fi`, it equals `if A then if ! B then C fi; else C fi`.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 2):

This construction (so called one-line if statement) uses executable part as a condition assuming that it's true. But if "true" part returns false, second part will also be executed.

Here's the example:

```
[[ 0 == 0 ]] && (echo "Good"; exit 1) || echo "Bad"
```

Condition is true, but executable part after it returns false (`exit 1`), so `[[ 0 == 0 ]] && (echo "Good"; exit 1)` part is `false` and we should check another condition of `||` operator.

As a result, we are executing both `true` and `false` parts.

If you need to fit it into a single line, you can add `|| true` to "true" part:

```
[[ 0 == 0 ]] && (echo "Good" || true) || echo "Bad"
```

In this case, even if `echo "Good"` returns false, the whole "true" part will return `true` and false second part of `||` will not be checked.