# Why does the Linux shell command test -ef not work on soft links as its manual describes?

Tags: linux, shell, symlink, hardlink, ln

I create a `hard` link to `student.sh` and a `soft` link to `student.sh`.
The `hard` links have different inodes than `soft` links.
But when comparing the `soft` with `student.sh` by using the `test -ef` command, it does not work as expected.
I had checked the manuals of the `ln` and `test` commands but still confused with them.

```bash
$ man test

# FILE1 -ef FILE2
#   FILE1 and FILE2 have the same device and inode numbers
```

```bash
$ ln /home/pi/Desktop/links/student.sh hard
$ ln -s /home/pi/Desktop/links/student.sh soft

$ ls -ial
278224 drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi 4096  6月  5 23:31 .
262125 drwxr-xr-x 12 pi pi 4096  6月  5 23:17 ..
278227 -rwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi   43  6月  5 23:20 hard
278225 lrwxrwxrwx  1 pi pi   33  6月  5 23:31 soft -> /home/pi/Desktop/links/student.sh
278227 -rwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi   43  6月  5 23:20 student.sh
```

##### test

```bash
# ❌ inode is different
$ [ ./student.sh -ef ./soft ] && echo yes || echo no
yes

$ [ ./student.sh -ef ./hard ] && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

> update test case

`./test.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ ./student.sh -ef ./soft ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi

if [[ ./student.sh -ef ./hard ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

```bash
$ ./test.sh 
yes
yes
```

##### wanted

```bash
# inode is different, so it should output no ✅
$ [ ./student.sh -ef ./soft ] && echo yes || echo no
no

$ [ ./student.sh -ef ./hard ] && echo yes || echo no
yes
```

Comment: Because it follows links and compares the targets.

Comment: This allows you to do `if [ $link1 -ef $link2 ]` to test if they both refer to the same file.

Comment: BTW, note that `a && b || c` is **not** the same as `if a; then b; else c; fi`. Use the latter unless you're very sure -- see [one-liner if/else not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76371824/one-liner-if-else-not-working-as-intended) and/or [BashPitfalls #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right, but in my case I just wanted to make testing easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Barmar mentioned in a comment, and as documented in [the `bash` manual section on conditional expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

> Unless otherwise specified, primaries that operate on files follow symbolic links and operate on the target of the link, rather than the link itself.

You can use [`stat(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) to get the device number and inode *without* following symbolic links, and compare those values, though:

```bash
$ is_same_file () { test "$(stat -c "%d %i" "$1")" = "$(stat -c "%d %i" "$2")"; }
$ if is_same_file student.sh hard; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
$ if is_same_file student.sh soft; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

This should work on any POSIXish shell, not just `bash`, as long as the GNU coreutils `stat(1)` command is available, which seems a safe bet since you're talking about Linux. Might need to be adjusted if using some other enviroment; the [NetBSD `stat(1)`](https://man.netbsd.org/stat.1), for example, uses `-f` instead of `-c`).

Comment: @xgqfrms please see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29

Comment: I'm using `bash` and `zsh` and they both test fine. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html